# Unable to build project after new windows install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I recently bought a new computer. After getting everything setup, I installed visual studio community 2019 and gitkraken and cloned down my project(which was building and running fine prior to changing computers) and I'm running into an issue. It's a game dev project using MonoGame.

[image: Image from Gyazo]
These are the errors that I'm receiving currently. I've tried multiple versions of MonoGame including 3.0, 3.5, and 3.7. I've attempted to reinstall redistributables, I've cloned into multiple directories, I've attempted building a different project(a fork of the same project that I've worked on more recently on my previous pc). I have a friend that works on the project with me, he was able to clone into a new directory and build immediately. I've attempted building the content package in the MGCB manually and am also running into an issue where it's not finding a specific font file(that i've verified is installed on my computer, and also tried dropping in the correct directory for building, but have had no luck there. However, I feel like this is a separate issue, but it may provide some insight to someone who is more experienced than I.)

Ideally, this project should clone down and build just fine on a fresh install. It always has before, but there's something going on here that I'm not sure about. I've tried several different things and have hit a wall. There isn't much online about this specific issue that I've seen, so if anyone has any ideas I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: There's some troubleshooting pointers in [this Github issue](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/6751). Maybe check those out and then report back.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I attempted to build using the pipeline tool(as suggested in the link you posted) to see the error messages and received the same error on my NameFont.spritefont as the one shown in the above picture. I removed reference to that font and changed to another spritefont(that isn't throwing any error), and my project is building correctly. I'm still not sure why this font that I've verified to be installed on my pc is giving me some index out of range error. It's the Ubuntu Mono font. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If you cant fix the font issue, try to use another font name.

Comment: @KruSuPhy: I can only speculate. Does it need to be a specific format (TTF/OTF/something else)? Could it have been compiled *for* Ubuntu (i.e. can Windows fully support that font?). There could simply be some limitations -- fonts are tricky things. You could try similar fonts like Droid Sans Mono, or Roboto Mono, or Inconsolata. Maybe you can get a feel for which ones work and which ones don't.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Yeah it's very weird. The font has been in the project for quite some time(over 1.5 years) and we've never had an issue before. It's just strange that after getting a brand new pc it would suddenly be incompatible. I will continue to investigate and update if I happen to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was something simple as usual, a product of my own stupidity. When I first downloaded the font, I extracted and right click > install. So the font was installed on the PC. I spent a couple days on this issue, and at some point when trying to reinstall the font there was a new option that hadn't been there before called 'Install for all users' with the shield icon next to it. Previously, I'd only had the option to 'Install' without the shield icon. Not sure exactly what the difference is between these two options showing up, but once I clicked 'Install for all users', the issue was solved. So I guess initially the font was only installed for my specific user account. I'm not sure why this is an issue or why the option to install for everyone wasn't available previously, but this is what solved the problem.

Comment: Was the OS on this machine Windows 10? Forgive my ignorance, I am not a Windows user.

Comment: @Strom Yes, Windows 10 Professional. Sorry for the late reply.